# JSF Converter for p:selectOneListbox returns NullPointerException

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I try to implement a converter for my `<p:selectOneListbox>`. The list should hold `child` objects. The converter is declared in my `faces-config.xml`. The firstnames of `children` get displayed in my list on the view.

The problem is that I always get a `NullPointerException` by calling `List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>(childService.getAllChildren());` in `ChildConverter`. But there are `child` objects in my DB. The same method is called for another table and returns `child` objects.

My listbox:

```
<p:selectOneListbox id="childList" value="#{caregiverController.caregiver.child}" converter="childConverter" var="t" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
  <f:selectItems value="#{childController.children}" var="child" itemLabel="#{child.firstName}" itemValue="#{child}" />

  <p:column>
    <p:graphicImage name="pictures/tiger.jpg" width="32" height="32" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{t.firstName}" />
  </p:column>
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

My converter:

```
@FacesConverter("childConverter")
public class ChildConverter implements Converter {

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
    if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
        try {
            ChildService childService = (ChildService) fc.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("childService");
            List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>(childService.getAllChildren());
            return children.get(Integer.parseInt(value));
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid theme."));
        }
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
    if(object != null) {
        return String.valueOf(((Child) object).getId());
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: is childService null? Please debug/clarify more

Comment: childService is not **null**.. method getAllChildren() yields some childrend when i call it from another class

Comment: Then the problem is in your childService class. Debug that. Not java-se, jsf or PrimeFaces related. I'm inclined to remove all these tags but then none are left...